# Maclaurin Series of ${e}$ and $\frac{1}{e}$ with 3 decimal accuracy

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, taylor-expansion

I was using Maclaurin series to compute $e$ and $\frac{1}{e}$ to 3 decimal accuracy. Both of them have 7 terms.
$$e\approx1+1+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}+\frac{1}{5!}+\frac{1}{6!}$$
$$\frac{1}{e}\approx1-1+\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}-\frac{1}{5!}+\frac{1}{6!}$$
I'm asked to explain the feature of number of terms. I've tried with remainders, but I didn't find a way to show that. Could you plz help me? And also, I wonder whether it is only for 3 decimal or it is for any decimal accuracy? Thank you in advance!

Comment: $|e^{-1}-(1-\dots+1/6!)|=|-1/7!+(1/8!-1/9!)+(1/10!-1/11!)+\dots|\le1/7!$, where $7!=5040$ has $4$ digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Lagrange error bound:

$$|R_n| ≤ \frac{M}{(n+1)!} (x-x_0)^{n+1}$$

Let's do $e$ first. The Taylor approximation is centred at $x_0 = 0$ with $x = 1$. The maximum value of the $(n+1)$th derivative is just the maximum value of $e^x$ in the domain $[0,1]$, which is just $e$. We want to find the least value of $n$ where $|R_n| ≤ 0.001$, or:

$$\frac{e}{(n+1)!} \cdot 1 ≤ 0.001 \implies n ≥ 6$$

You can do the other case similarly.

Comment: Just a note: $n = 6$ is not the sixth term, but the term with $x^6$ which is the seventh term.